# How to wrap text in a textarea in extjs

Tags: extjs5

I have a textarea used in my `extjs` form . I want the text inside the textarea wrap to next line before it comes to the end of width .

```
tDescription = new Ext.form.TextField({
    fieldLabel:"Description"
    ,name:"Description"
    ,tabIndex:3
    ,width:250
    ,height:90
    ,allowBlank:false
    ,disableKeyFilter:true
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you must change to new **Ext.form.TextArea**, becouse this class creates a multiline text field